# Null Pointer Exception for SeekBar set Max and set Progress

Tags: java, android, oop, exception, seekbar

I have a simple seek bar with which I intend to adjust the system volume with. However it has been throwing a null pointer exception for quite some time:

```
int max = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Log.d("tag","+"+max);
        volumeSeekbar.setMax(max);
        int progress = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        volumeSeekbar.setProgress(progress);

        volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"HEREO",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2)
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress, 0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+progress,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Both progress and max turn out to be valid integers. However, a null pointer exception is continuously thrown!

> 12-24 09:23:07.471  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
> 12-24 09:23:07.472  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at com.company.volume.MainActivity.initControls(MainActivity.java:71)
> 12-24 09:23:07.472  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at com.company.volume.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
> 12-24 09:23:07.472  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
> 12-24 09:23:07.473  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
> 12-24 09:23:07.473  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
> 12-24 09:23:07.473  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
> 12-24 09:23:07.473  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
> 12-24 09:23:07.474  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
> 12-24 09:23:07.474  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> 12-24 09:23:07.474  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
> 12-24 09:23:07.474  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
> 12-24 09:23:07.475  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
> 12-24 09:23:07.475  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
> 12-24 09:23:07.475  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
> 12-24 09:23:07.475  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
> 12-24 09:23:07.475  11705-11705/com.company.volume W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Where is the code where you are setting the volumeSeekbar instance? Something like `volumeSeekbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar)`

Comment: Have you referred to the view during onCreate() of MainActivity.class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably your `volumeSeekbar` is `null`. not `progress` and `max` values. Make sure that `volumeSeekbar` defined correctly.

Comment: I had a navigation drawer and I defined it in a sub view. So when I tried to call my seek bar in on create it was null. Thank you.